# Extract Java element based on its corresponding XML element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, abstract-syntax-tree, inria-spoon

I have a XML file resulted from an input java file. I also have `xPath` expressions for the XML file.

I need a function that receives one xPath expression and return its java element (in the abstract syntax tree). I tried the below code:

1. First extract XML element based on the input xPath expression.

   ```
   XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   String query = "//unit[1]/unit[1]/class[1]/block[1]/function[6]"; //a method
   Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(query).evaluate(XmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
   ```
2. However, I do not know how to link extracted `XML` node to Java element in the source code.

PS:
The reslut should be a node in the abstract syntax tree. I have AST created by [spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/). Therefore, in the above example, I want to extract related `CtMethodImpl`.

`node.getTextContent()` is not the answer as it is possible that there is more than one instance with the similar text content.

Comment: What abstract syntax tree? What Java element? As written, your question is unanswerable. Please edit it with an example of your input, and an example of what you want for output.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no 'direct' way of doing this.

This: `"//unit[1]/unit[1]/class[1]/block[1]/function[6]"` is what we call a **signature** in the sense that it uniquely identifies an element (somehow).

What I would do is to create a spoon processor and go through the entire AST checking each element to see if it matches the signature.

```
public class ProcessorExample <E extends CtElement> extends AbstractProcessor<E> {

    HashMap<String, Node> nodes;
    //Sets your XML Nodes here, sorted by signature
    public void setNodes(HashMap<String, Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(E element) {
        if (nodes.containsKey(signature(element))) {
            Node n = nodes.get(signature(element));
            //YOU FOUND IT!
        }
    }

    private String signature(E element) {
        //YOU MUST PROVIDE THIS IMPLEMENTATION
        //TO MATCH YOUR "//unit[1]/unit[1]/class[1]/block[1]/function[6]"
        //KIND OF SIGNATURE
        return null;
    }
}
```